# How to match two consecutive alphabets like AA, BB not AB, BD with Regular expression in python?

Tags: python, regex, alphabetical

I would like to match string of two consecutive alphabets like AA, BB not AB, BD. 
Python 3.x is my language. Please consider valid alphabets would be capitalized.
The followings are examples for valid and not valid strings:
To be honest, ^[A-Z]{2} would not work.

- Valid: AA, ZZ, DD, EE,
- Not valid: AB, DDD, aA, Aa, Cd, DE

Comment: does input string contain multiple words?

Comment: @Roman, No, the input would be a single word.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use grouping to achieve that.

Here is a RegEx that will match any uppercase alphabetical character twice : [`([A-Z])\1`](https://regex101.com/r/dKgmQp/2)

**[Demo.](https://regex101.com/r/dKgmQp/2)**

Comment: i think he wants only capital letters

Comment: @StavrosAvramidis Yeah, I updated it, thanks.